# Why I am unable to execute insmod on the docker container?

Tags: linux, docker, seccomp

I have started an unprivileged docker container and trying to start the privileged exec session. It has CAP_SYS_MODULE capabilities, but still, I am getting operations not permitted in insmod.

```
docker start -it -d --name test ubuntu
docker exec -it --privileged test sh
...
/ # insmod shell.ko
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module reverse-shell.ko: Operation not permitted
```

Then I tried to start the container with seccomp unconfined and executed the same commands and it is working

```
docker start -it -d --security-opts seccomp=unconfined --name test2 ubuntu
docker exec -it --privileged test2 sh
...
/ # insmod shell.ko
```

Now coming back to the seccomp, I see it blocks the syscalls based on the default profile from moby, where I see the [finit_module is allowed](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/profiles/seccomp/default.json#L671). So why did my kernel module didn't loaded the first time with the seccomp confined container?

Comment: have you run insmod under strace to see which syscall was blocked? Maybe finit_module was not the problem but some check before that?

Comment: I found no problem until the program tried open the kernel object. `openat("/root/shell.ko"....) = 3`

Comment: But `openat(...) = 3` means that openat completed successfully. Which syscalls does strace tell you are actually failing and with what error code? If strace does show `finit_module(...) = -1 EPERM` then this means that either Docker's seccomp profile is behaving differently than expected, or that the process running with the container doesn't actually have CAP_SYS_MODULE. You can inspect current capabilities with `capsh --print`, or more directly here `capsh --has-p=cap_sys_module; echo $?` (should have exit code 0).

Comment: it does have the privileges. `docker exec -it --privileged <name> sh` do add all the caps. What's confusing is that on the [docker page](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/seccomp/#significant-syscalls-blocked-by-the-default-profile), it says finit_module is blocked in default but in the [default.json](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/profiles/seccomp/default.json#L671-L673) it is allowed.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this appears to be a couple of things. Firstly when you start a non-privileged container and then exec into it with privilege, the seccomp filter is still enabled. Second one is that the seccomp profile does block the  finit_module call.

The output below shows a re-creation of what I *think* you were going for in the first setup. Using [amicontained](https://github.com/genuinetools/amicontained) it's possible to look at the blocked syscalls in the privileged exec shell and we can see (if you scroll a long way to the right :) ) that FINIT_MODULE is blocked.

```
❯ docker run -d --name test raesene/alpine-containertools
c5c7a7b95ea0e531450b8843c85db0f54f7997ddb8273c8f97ae9bd0376685ab

rorym in  cuilean in  ⛵ kadmin@kubeadm2node () ~
❯ docker exec -it --privileged test /bin/bash
bash-5.1# amicontained
Container Runtime: not-found
Has Namespaces:
    pid: true
    user: false
AppArmor Profile: docker-default (enforce)
Capabilities:
    BOUNDING -> chown dac_override dac_read_search fowner fsetid kill setgid setuid setpcap linux_immutable net_bind_service net_broadcast net_admin net_raw ipc_lock ipc_owner sys_module sys_rawio sys_chroot sys_ptrace sys_pacct sys_admin sys_boot sys_nice sys_resource sys_time sys_tty_config mknod lease audit_write audit_control setfcap mac_override mac_admin syslog wake_alarm block_suspend audit_read
Seccomp: filtering
Blocked Syscalls (59):
    SYSLOG SETSID USELIB USTAT SYSFS VHANGUP PIVOT_ROOT _SYSCTL ACCT SETTIMEOFDAY MOUNT UMOUNT2 SWAPON SWAPOFF REBOOT SETHOSTNAME SETDOMAINNAME IOPL IOPERM CREATE_MODULE INIT_MODULE DELETE_MODULE GET_KERNEL_SYMS QUERY_MODULE QUOTACTL NFSSERVCTL GETPMSG PUTPMSG AFS_SYSCALL TUXCALL SECURITY LOOKUP_DCOOKIE CLOCK_SETTIME VSERVER MBIND SET_MEMPOLICY GET_MEMPOLICY KEXEC_LOAD ADD_KEY REQUEST_KEY KEYCTL MIGRATE_PAGES UNSHARE MOVE_PAGES PERF_EVENT_OPEN FANOTIFY_INIT NAME_TO_HANDLE_AT OPEN_BY_HANDLE_AT SETNS PROCESS_VM_READV PROCESS_VM_WRITEV KCMP FINIT_MODULE KEXEC_FILE_LOAD BPF USERFAULTFD PKEY_MPROTECT PKEY_ALLOC PKEY_FREE
```